# refactoring complex linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have created this linq pipeline that returns a dto that suits my needs perfectly.
But as I try to keep my code clean I don't see how someone else's than me could easily read it. Any clean way I could do that?

```
    public static IEnumerable<SubscriptionOfferList> GetSubscriptionOffers(this IEnumerable<Product> products, IEnumerable<Plan> plans) =>
         products
             .GroupBy(p => p.Metadata["SubscriptionType"])
             .Select(productGroup => new SubscriptionOfferList
             {
                Name = productGroup.Key,
                Offers = productGroup.Select(p => new SubscriptionOffer
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Price = p.Metadata["SubscriptionPrice"],
                    Plans = plans
                    .Where(plan => plan.ProductId == p.Id)
                    .Select(plan => new PaymentPlan
                    {
                        Name = plan.Nickname,
                        Id = plan.Id,
                        Price = plan.Tiers ?? new List<PlanTier>
                        {
                            new PlanTier
                            {
                                UnitAmount = plan.Amount.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                UpTo = null
                            }
                        },
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList(),
             });
```

Comment: Break up the sub queries with some well named local methods. e.g. `IEnumerable<Plan> GetPlansByProductID(int)`

Comment: not sure how to accomplish that, while being in an extension method, could you show an example please?

Comment: Sure, you could break it up like the answers show, but it looks really straightforward to me.

Comment: @XavSc local functions work just fine in extension methods. You won't be able to use an expression bodied method if it defines local functions, however, and will have to add a return statement and some curlys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why comments are bad, but just break it up into smaller functions

```
private static List<Plan> MakePlans(IEnumerable<Plan> plans, int pid)
{
    return plans
            .Where(plan => plan.ProductId == pid)
            .Select(plan => new PaymentPlan
            {
                Name = plan.Nickname,
                Id = plan.Id,
                Price = plan.Tiers ?? new List<PlanTier>
                {
                    new PlanTier
                    {
                        UnitAmount = plan.Amount.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        UpTo = null
                    }
                },
            }).ToList();
}

public static IEnumerable<SubscriptionOfferList> GetSubscriptionOffers(this IEnumerable<Product> products, IEnumerable<Plan> plans) =>
     products
         .GroupBy(p => p.Metadata["SubscriptionType"])
         .Select(productGroup => new SubscriptionOfferList
         {
            Name = productGroup.Key,
            Offers = productGroup.Select(p => new SubscriptionOffer
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                Price = p.Metadata["SubscriptionPrice"],
                Plans = MakePlans(plans, p.Id)
            }).ToList(),
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a comment on top of the method and some comments throughout the linq parts what they are doing, that should be fine as long as query works well.

Comment: in clean code comments are considered a noise, methods should be self explanatory

Comment: that's just wrong. I dare you to name one big piece of code that comments aren't needed for @XavSc

Comment: Sorry I won't explain myself as to why I said that as this is not a thread intended for debate, you can read clean code book to see if you re convinced or not, or a shorter version you can find across the web like this one : http://apdevblog.com/comments-in-code/

Comment: It's true that it is hard to write a self-explanatory big-piece of code. But why should it be a big-piece? Isn't it better to have each piece of code doing only one thing.